# how to update partial string in SQL with new data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have string like `Descr` = `ANY TEXT 31-Jan-2019 to 30-Jan-2020`. Is it possible to replace these dates with new dates in the text ?

New Data:

```
CycleBeginDate = '01/01/2020'
CycleEndDate = '12/31/2022'
Update Desc should be `ANY TEXT 01-Jan-2020 to 31-Dec-2022`
```

Comment: Will the text always end with the dates?

Comment: Does 31-Jan-2019 need to fall between CycleBegin and CycleEnd? And rows may thus have any date inbetween Begin/&/End?  Then is DATEADD(year, 1, '31-Jan-2019') and DATEADD(year, 1, '30-Jan-2020') applied to both from and to dates?  Or should the from date revert to first of month and the end date extend to two years later minus 1 day?  The specs are a little loose and need more info.

Comment: You just need to convert one date format to another?

Comment: @jamie  No Dates only end of the text. Always 01-Jan-2020 to 31-Dec-2022 end

Comment: @Programnik updated post

Comment: Just because nobody has said this yet: You should not store such data within a string. Each description should live in a related table, where the row has `text`, `from` and `to` in separate columns. The string you show us should be created just for output purposes...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and much easier if you can assume that the dates will always be AT THE END of the "desc" value (like you have in your sample) and that the dates are always zero-filled (1st of Jan would be "01-Jan-2019" and not '1-Jan-2019)... meaning the text of dates at the end can be assumed to always be 26 bytes long; you can....

```
update t
     set desc = left( 'ANY TEXT 31-Jan-2019 to 30-Jan-2020', len( 'ANY TEXT 31-Jan-2019 to 30-Jan-2020' ) - 26 ) + @CycleBeginDate + ' to ' + @CycleEndDate
    from YourTable t
```

This obviously gets much more difficult if the date range you want to modify can either be formatted differently (not always 26 bytes of text to replace) or can be located at different locations in your "desc" value.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick and, for fun, I set it up so that it works even regardless of where the dates appear in the string.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'Blah, blah... yadda, yadda... 31-Jan-2019 to 30-Jan-2020!!!'
--'Descr = ANY TEXT 31-Jan-2019 to 30-Jan-2020';

DECLARE @CycleBeginDate DATE = '01/01/2020';
DECLARE @CycleEndDate   DATE = '12/31/2022';

SELECT NewString = STUFF(STUFF(@string,pos.D1,11,f.D1),pos.D1+15,11,f.D2)
FROM   (VALUES('%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-2[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),@CycleBeginDate,106),' ','-'),
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),@CycleEndDate,106),' ','-'))) AS f(DPat,D1,D2)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX(f.DPat,@string)))                    AS pos(D1);
```

**Returns:**

```
NewString
------------------------------------------------------------
Blah, blah... yadda, yadda... 01-Jan-2020 to 31-Dec-2022!!!
```